# Invoking Google Apps Script Rest API from Photoshop script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, photoshop

I am working on Photoshop and Google Apps Script combination API. I have created API URL in Google Apps Script, but I can't make and get the result in my Photoshop Script.

[This is the complete URL](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbza_1YFg7Gux0qs_zRnrjNoIumNA-pTlAzUYKor9DIYTEWVRQjf/exec?action=get&prodid=1934), when you click this you will get the JSON result (World Cup Italy).

```
    var ui = require("ui");
    var http = require("http");

   var api = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbza_1YFg7Gux0qs_zRnrjNoIumNA-pTlAzUYKor9DIYTEWVRQjf/exec";


function makeGet(url, input, token){
   var req = new http.HTTPRequest("GET", api+"?action=get&prodid=1934 World Cup Italy");
   req.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   var res = req.do();
   if(res.status != 200){
     // alert('ddd');
    return (res.body);
    }
 //  $.writeln(res.status == 200);
 //  $.writeln(res.body);
   return JSON.parse(res.body);
}
```

How can I invoke this API from the Photoshop Script?

Comment: look at your publishing options to be anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

You'll run into a few obstacles with Photoshop and API calls, but the information below should set you on the right path.

Firstly, Photoshop only exposes a Socket object for TCP.  Below is a snippet for how to use the Socket object from the estk.aenhancers.com JavaScript Tools Guide CC: http://estk.aenhancers.com/6%20-%20External%20Communication%20Tools/socket-object.html?highlight=socket

```
reply = "";
conn = new Socket;

// access Adobe's home page
if (conn.open ("www.adobe.com:80")) {

    // send a HTTP GET request
    conn.write ("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n");

    // and read the server's reply
    reply = conn.read(999999);

    conn.close();
}
```

Second, Photoshop doesn't have native support for JSON.parse / JSON.stringify, so you'll need an external library.  I suggest tonton-pixel's JSON Action Manager, specifically jamJSON: http://www.tonton-pixel.com/JSON%20Action%20Manager/jsDoc/symbols/jamJSON.html

Hope this helps!